# I can not found what's wrong with SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this snippet of code

And got the `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Is there any better debugger to show the more understandable and accuracy error on Mac ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    $('.fancy .slot').jSlots({
        number : 2,
        winnerNumber : 1,
        spinner : '#playFancy',
        easing : 'easeOutSine',
        time : 7000,
        loops : 6,
        onStart : function() {
            $('.slot').removeClass('winner');
        },
        onWin : function(winCount, winners) {
            // only fires if you win

            $.each(winners, function() {
                this.addClass('winner');
            });

            // react to the # of winning slots                 
            if ( winCount === 1 ) {
                alert('You got ' + winCount + ' 7!!!');
            } 
            else if ( winCount > 1 ) {
                alert('You got ' + winCount + ' 7’s!!!');
            }

        }
    });
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `function` keyword:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    // code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you, may I ask a offensive question, I don't if it is my illusion that I think Javascript interpreter can get mis-leading error message for a beginner compared with java php ruby python ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the first { after document.ready should look like this

$( document ).ready(function() {

});